# Let $x_1,x_2,x_3...$ be all consecutive positive roots of the equation $\tan x = x.$ Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(x_n-x_{n-1}).$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, contest-math

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3...$ be all consecutive positive roots of the equation $\tan x = x.$ Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(x_n-x_{n-1}).$

I feel like the answer is $0$, as the gap between $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$ is getting smaller and smaller.

My attempt: Note that $ n\pi\leq x_n \leq (n+1)\pi$. However, $\pi \leq x_n - x_{n-1} \leq \pi$ and I couldn't use Squeeze theorem to conclude.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264875/solution-for-the-trigonometric-linear-function/2265081#2265081

Comment: Have you tried plotting this? I don't think the answer could be $0$.

Comment: G. H. Hardy solved this in the 1930's, iirc.

Comment: How hardy solved it?